# how to speed up processing very large pdml files with iterparse in lxml?

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

My files are normally over 8GB, so I used the solutions of Liza Daly's fast_iter. However, it's not finished after almost 2 days. I found through cProfile that xpath takes nearly half of time. How can I speed up it?

Here's an example of my pdml files:

```
<pdml>
 <packet>
  <proto name="geninfo">    
    <field name="timestamp"  value="1"/>
  </proto>
  <proto name="frame">    
    <field name="b1"/>
  </proto>
 </packet>
</pdml>
```

Here's my solution:

```
from lxml import etree    
context = etree.iterparse(infilename,tag='packet', huge_tree=True)

my_dict = fast_iter(context, process_packet)

def fast_iter(context, func, *args, **kwargs):

    my_dict = {}
    for event, elem in context:
        geninfo = elem.xpath("proto[@name='geninfo']")
        frame = elem.xpath("proto[@name='frame']")
        if not geninfo or not frame:
            elem.clear() 
            while elem.getprevious() is not None:
                del elem.getparent()[0]
            continue            

        item = func(elem, *args, **kwargs)
        elem.clear() 
        if not my_dict.has_key(item[0]):
            my_dict[item[0]]=[]
        my_dict[item[0]].append(item[1])    

        while elem.getprevious() is not None:
            del elem.getparent()[0]

    del context
    return my_dict


def process_packet(elem):


    temp_list = None

    timestamp = unicode(elem.xpath("proto[@name='geninfo']/field[@name='timestamp']/@value")[0])

...

  temp_list = [timestamp, ...]
  return temp_list
```

Comment: I rechecked my files, they are over 50GBs. When I used a piece of it (about 1GB) for testing, it took about 0.2s. Then, why 2 days for 50GB? Did I do something wrong?